# Override get in DomainClass

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I am using hibernate filter to filter the domain objects, that every user is only seeing his/her data.

This is working expect for .get().

The plugins page proposes to use .findById().

The reason for that is that get is not considered as a query and my hibernate filter is not applied. Hence the user would see data of another user which of course he shouldn't.

I am now looking for an efficient way to replace all my .get() with .findBy().

Is there a way to achieve this by extension?

All my domain-classes extend BaseDomainClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the *get()* method using the Groovy metaClass. You can do so by putting this inside the *init* closure in your *Bootstrap.groovy*.

```
BaseDomainClass.metaClass.static.get = {Serializable id ->
    delegate.findById(id)
}
```

Note: You may have to **import** *BaseDomainClass* into *Bootstrap.groovy*.